# How to get the value of a ComboBox in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I want to show the value of a ComboBox in it's Change event handler. The labelField is assigned dynamically, so that I don't know what it is when I run the event handler

```
cmbArea.labelField = qry.outFields[0];
```

I was hoping that I can have access to the value of selectedItem like:

```
   protected function cmbArea_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void{ 

       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Alert.show(event.target.selectedItem.value);
   }
```

But it didn't work.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Flex and Spark?

Comment: net.uk.sweet, Yes. The ComboBox is defined like:    `<s:ComboBox id="cmbArea" width="288" change="cmbArea_changeHandler(event)"/>`

Comment: Can anybody explain why I've got negative vote on this question. Did I do something wrong?!

Comment: I didn't vote you down but looking at your question, I think it could be improved by including more of the relevant code, the error message or details of the incorrect behaviour you're seeing, and the Flex 4 and ActionScript 3.0 tags. Don't let it get you down though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the following line and seems it works:

```
Alert.show(event.target.selectedItem[event.target.labelField]);
```

Comment: Hey Fred, did you know you can accept your own answer? The points you'll get will more than cover that down vote :)

Comment: Hi  Ian, thank you for your tip. I thought that someone else may find it useful and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to debug this without seeing your data provider code or the error message. However, it doesn't matter that the labelField is assigned dynamically. What you have will work if elements in your data provider have a property named "value". If the only property in your data provider is the one you assign as the labelField, you should be able to access it in your change handler with the following:

```
Alert.show(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem);
```

Comment: The data provider is an ArrayCollection which received data from a GIS web service. It has multiple properties and when I'm in the event procedure, I don't know which property is assigned as labelField. I'm sorry if the code is not clear enough. I'm using a sample code for fetching data from the web service and I don't understand it well. Thank you for your response anyway. It guided me to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            protected function comboBox_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show(comboBox.selectedItem);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:ComboBox id="comboBox"
                change="comboBox_changeHandler(event)">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>Item 1</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item 2</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item 3</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:ComboBox>

</s:Application>
```